# Excel Vba: Looping through userform controls to count and identify empty textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

@cdp1802
This is what I tried
Which came out wrong

I added other dept And tried to see the possibility of storing the value of other controls in an array.... obviously not the best way for that

Primarily the user needs to enter a service before specifying the quantity and then there's a code that already multiplies the rate of the service and the quantity specified
But in other to capture this in the database... based on every "Txt_Qty" entry
Txt_qtyAccomodation...has a textbox for service entry that is named "txt_accomodation"
Txt_qtyHaematology...  has a textbox for service entry that is named "cmb_haematology"
And so on

Also I need to capture the quantity and cost as well
....

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim dept, details, service, Quantity, Cost, i As Long
Dim zh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long

Set zh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PublicDatabase")
LastRow = zh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1


dept = Array("Accomodation", "Consultation", "Haematology", _
    "Histopathology", "Nursingcare", "Others1", _
    "Others2", "Microbiology", "Reviews", "Radiology1", "Radiology2", "Radiology3", "Pharmacy1", _
    "Pharmacy2", "Pharmacy3", "Phamacy4", "Pharmacy5", "Pharmacy6")
    
service = Array(Me.txt_initialconsultation.Value, Me.txt_Review.Value, Me.txt_nursingCare.Value, _
Me.txt_Accomodation.Value, Me.cmb_haematology.Value, Me.cmb_histopathology.Value, Me.cmb_Microbiology, _
Me.cmb_Other1.Value, Me.cmb_other2.Value, Me.Cmb_Radiology1.Value, Me.Cmb_Radiology2.Value, _
Me.Cmb_radiology3.Value, Me.Cmb_Pharmacy1.Value, Me.Cmb_Pharmacy2.Value, Me.Cmb_Pharmacy3.Value, _
Me.Cmb_Pharmacy4.Value, Me.Cmb_Pharmacy5.Value, Me.Cmb_Pharmacy6.Value)

Quantity = Array(Me.txt_QtyAccomodation.Value, Me.txt_QtyConsultation.Value, Me.txt_QtyHaematology.Value, _
Me.txt_QtyHistopathology.Value, Me.txt_QtyMicrobiology.Value, Me.txt_QtyNursingcare.Value, Me.txt_QtyOthers1.Value, _
Me.txt_QtyOthers2.Value, Me.txt_QtyPhamacy4.Value, Me.txt_QtyPharmacy1.Value, Me.txt_QtyPharmacy2.Value, Me.txt_QtyPharmacy3.Value, _
Me.txt_QtyPharmacy5.Value, Me.txt_QtyPharmacy6.Value, Me.txt_QtyRadiology1.Value, Me.txt_QtyRadiology2.Value, Me.txt_QtyRadiology3, _
Me.txt_QtyReviews.Value)

Cost = Array(Me.txt_costAccomodation.Value, Me.txt_CostCOnsultation.Value, Me.txt_CostHaematology.Value, _
Me.txt_CostHistopathology.Value, Me.txt_CostMicrobiology.Value, Me.txt_CostOthers1.Value, _
Me.txt_CostNursingCare.Value, Me.txt_CostOthers2.Value, Me.txt_CostPharmacy1.Value, Me.txt_CostPharmacy2.Value, _
Me.txt_CostPharmacy3.Value, Me.txt_CostPharmacy4.Value, Me.txt_CostPharmacy5.Value, Me.txt_CostPharmacy6.Value, _
Me.txt_CostRadiology1.Value, Me.txt_CostRadiology2.Value, Me.txt_CostRadiology3.Value)

   
details = PatientDetails()
   
Dim ccont As Control
For i = 0 To UBound(dept)
    Set ccont = Me.Controls("Txt_Qty" & dept(i))
    If ccont.Value <> "" Then
        
        details(1, 1) = LastRow - 1
        zh.Cells(LastRow, 1).Resize(, 18) = details
        zh.Cells(LastRow, 19) = service
        zh.Cells(LastRow, 20) = Quantity
        zh.Cells(LastRow, 22) = Cost
LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Entered", vbInformation
```

End Sub

Comment: Are there other text boxes than the ones used in your code, which may be empty? I mean, it should be allowed to be empty... Why is it necessary to count them, if all of the text box should be checked against being empty?

Comment: It should be `Dim ccont As Control` singular

Comment: To count the number of empty textboxes in other to use that value to know the number of rows Patient details will repeat in the database(spreadsheet).... so in the big picture, when user enters 5different services On the form... it can repeat the Patient details based on the number of textboxes that are typed in (meaning there's a service)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through an array of the text box names checking values that are not empty.

Update1 - Added service and cost

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim dept, details, i As Long
    Dim zh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    
    Set zh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PublicDatabase")
    LastRow = zh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    dept = Array("Accomodation", "Consultation", "Nursingcare", _
         "Reviews", "Haematology", "Histopathology", _
         "Others1", "Others2", "Microbiology", _
         "Radiology1", "Radiology2", "Radiology3", _
         "Pharmacy1", "Pharmacy2", "Pharmacy3", _
         "Pharmacy4", "Pharmacy5", "Pharmacy6")
          
    details = PatientDetails()
       
    Dim qty As Control, cost As Control, service As Control
    For i = 0 To UBound(dept)
        Set qty = Me.Controls("Txt_Qty" & dept(i))
        Set cost = Me.Controls("Txt_Cost" & dept(i))
        Select Case Left(dept(i), 4)
            Case "Acco", "Cons", "Nurs", "Revi"
                Set service = Me.Controls("Txt_" & dept(i))
            Case Else
                Set service = Me.Controls("Cmb_" & dept(i))
        End Select

        If qty.Value <> "" Then
            details(1, 1) = LastRow - 1
            zh.Cells(LastRow, 1).Resize(, 18) = details
            zh.Cells(LastRow, 19) = service.Value
            zh.Cells(LastRow, 20) = qty.Value
            zh.Cells(LastRow, 22) = cost.Value
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Entered", vbInformation
End Sub

Private Function PatientDetails() As Variant
    Dim ar(1 To 1, 1 To 18)
    With PubDefense
        ar(1, 1) = 0
        ar(1, 2) = "DEFENCE HEALTH MAINTENANCE LTD (PUBLIC)"
        ar(1, 3) = .Txt_NameOfpDEFENSE.Value
        ar(1, 4) = "Nil"
        ar(1, 5) = .Txt_RefferrinProviderDefense.Value
        ar(1, 6) = .Txt_NHISNoDefense.Value
        ar(1, 7) = .Txt_AuthorizCodeDefense.Value
        ar(1, 8) = .Txt_HmoCodeDefense.Value
        ar(1, 9) = .Txt_DateOftreatmentDefense.Value
        ar(1, 10) = .Txt_DateOFadmDefense.Value
        ar(1, 11) = .Txt_DateOFdisDefense.Value
        ar(1, 12) = "Nil"
        ar(1, 13) = "Nil"
        ar(1, 14) = "Nil"
        ar(1, 15) = "Nil"
        ar(1, 16) = "Nil"
        ar(1, 17) = .Txt_DiagnosisDefense.Value
        ar(1, 18) = .Txt_PatAddressDEfense.Value
    End With
    PatientDetails = ar
End Function
```

Comment: This works impeccably well... only thing left is how the service entered, quantity and service rate can reflect in the database when "txt_qty" repeats !! That's in column 19, 20 and 21... because after the user enters a value in txt_qty he/she must have provided a service... that would be multiplied by the quantity entered to get the cost of the service.... how do I inculcate this to this code @cdp1802

Comment: @Israel Which controls have the service rate in ?

Comment: There were actually more than 9 “dept" so I added the other dept
And tried to store the cost, quantity and service controls somehow..In other to use in zh.cells(LastRow, column) but obviously I was off target…

Comment: @Israel Can you edit your question please rather than putting code in comments

Comment: Sorry about that, will do shortly

Comment: hello sir, my question has been edited.. I do appreciate your response and help

Comment: @israel OK do you have Me.txt_CostReviews is seems to be missing

Comment: Yes I do.... I omitted that.. my mistake !!

Comment: @Israel Ok see update. You need to rename `txt_Review` to `Txt_Reviews` and `txt_initialconsultation` to `Txt_Consultation` to be consistent with the cost and qty controls.

Comment: I have, to get it working it ensured I renamed most of the controls I thought I wouldn't matter... I'm so grateful for your help @cdp1802